# Mysql and snmp/mib

Tags: mysql

I am not sure if this is the right place but I was wondering if it is possible to monitor the non commercial version of mysql database (table, space..) via snmp.

http://www.mysql.com/products/community/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this a while back and came across mysql-snmp:
http://www.masterzen.fr/software-contributions/mysql-snmp-monitor-mysql-with-snmp/

I don't believe MySQL natively reports via SNMP.